# How to know my permissions for bitbucket repo?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Where can I see my permission level for someone's repository on bitbucket? I'm in a so called "cloud team". I've read [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-teams-321853005.html) and [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/organize-your-team-into-user-groups-665225542.html) from which I understood that I'm supposed to be in one of user groups which determines my access level. I couldn't find any info about which group I'm in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [overview page](https://bitbucket.org/dashboard/overview) shows your access level to a given repository.

[image: Access level is listed on the overview page]

Comment: unfortunately the overview page no longer shows that

Answer (score 41):

As of today, Access Level is visible on the vertical panel on the right side of the Source/Master page of the repo. See this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: This solution is still working in August 2021

Answer (score 18):

As per new bitbucket you see the permission details, once you click the 'clone' side menu.

Refer the screenshot

[image]

Note: As bitbucket tend to change UI multiple time(s), this answer may subject to not work for you. As of April'2020 UI was as given in screen shot.

Comment: this has been removed from that clone dialog now :(

Comment: @Matthew It must have been changed recently, otherwise by April'2020 it used to be at clone menu.

Comment: In our on-prem Bitbucket, the read-only warning only displays if you don't have write permission, and doesn't display any notices if you have read+write.